# Menu icons broke after reboot

Tags: icons, menu, settings

A picture is worth a thousand words...

[image: missing app icons]

The app icons in the menu bar for `wallch` and `syntastic` were replaced by the broken-monitor icon after a reboot and I'm not sure why. They were working fine previously.

Any ideas how I can fix this? I haven't been able to find where they're defined or any other means to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact details, but for some reason those applications were removed from the file system even though they were still running in memory. I think it might have had to do with an `apt-get autoremove` that went awry but that's just a guess. Reinstalling and restarting the apps fixed the problem. Very strange. Thanks to anyone who investigated this.